# How to migrate from regular MySQL to Percona Server in production?

Tags: centos, mysql, migration, percona, xtradb

I'm running MySQL 5.0 in production on CentOS. How do I migrate to Percona Server 5.1 safely?

The documentation of Percona Server doesn't include any information on migrating. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a guess I'd say mysqldump your database from MySQL and reimport it into the Percona server.

I don't know if you can just fire up Percona server pointed to the same datadir as MySQL. Might be worth investigating.

Comment: You can just install Percona Server over MySQL. It is binary compatible.

Answer (score 8):

The data files are compatible with percona server. You just need to start percona server mysqld and everything will work.

Only when you enable some features (like extra rollback segments) on percona server, you might not be able to go back to mysql. but you rarely need to change this parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good tutorial
You need just remove mysql-server and install percona-server, that's all.

Percona and Mysql binary compatible!

```
apt-get remove mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common
apt-get autoremove
```

Than just add percona repo and

```
apt-get update
apt-get install percona-server-server
```

After that you can start Mysql and it will work

```
service mysql start
```

More complete tutorial you can find by link below

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-a-fresh-percona-server-or-replace-mysql

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers.

Comment: I improved my answer, please not vote down me

Answer (score -1):

It's pretty much the same upgrade path from 5.0 to 5.1, of course to make better use of Percona enhancements you should consult the wiki.